# How to set a postgres table default ID to uuid_generate_v4() with Django

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have been told to set all the table default IDs in my Django project to the value of the postgresql method `uuid_generate_v4()`.

An example of the current models I'm using is:

```py
import uuid

from django.db import models

class MyModel(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        ordering = ("my_var",)

    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, blank=True, editable=False)
    my_var = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=True)
```

I have come to understand that it would not be advised to mix SQLAlchemy with Django, so how can I best implement what is asked of me?

(Note: yes, `default=uuid.uuid4` isn't enough for what my project requires)

Comment: Have you looked at [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/postgres/functions/#randomuuid)? If you look at the source, it's just using a `Func` with template `GEN_RANDOM_UUID`. Not sure how that differs to `UUID_GENERATE_V4` but you can just implement the same way.

Comment: See [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/205902/postgresql-two-different-ways-to-generate-a-uuid-gen-random-uuid-vs-uuid-genera) for the difference.

Comment: @dirkgroten that first link is exactly what I needed! Thanks so much! Feel free to post it as an answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Django's `Func` to call built-in database functions. In fact, for PostgreSQL, Django supports [`RandomUUID`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/postgres/functions/#randomuuid) which is defined like this:

```
class RandomUUID(Func):
    template = 'GEN_RANDOM_UUID()'
    output_field = UUIDField()
```

and can be called like this:

```
from django.contrib.postgres.functions import RandomUUID

class MyModel(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=RandomUUID)
```

So if the postgreSQL **gen_random_uuid()** is not what you need (apparently it differs from **uuid_generate_v4()** as explained [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/205902/postgresql-two-different-ways-to-generate-a-uuid-gen-random-uuid-vs-uuid-genera)) just create your own `Func` class replacing the template with `template = 'UUID_GENERATE_V4()'`

Comment: It works for me so maybe you should explain exactly what error you get, what version of PostgreSQL you’re using, what version of Django you’re using...

Comment: I've tried this in Django 3.0.8 but it doesn't work, and I doubt that it has ever worked before. I can find no evidence that anyone else has done it like this before.
Two errors come up: `AttributeError: 'RandomUUID' object has no attribute 'replace'` and `ValidationError: RandomUUID()” is not a valid UUID.`

Comment: its is not working at migration time as default value, it will generate same value for all rows :)